# Prevent panels from overlapping in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

I am just getting started with wxPython.  I have the following code:

```
import wx

class SASFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent,id,title):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,title)
        groupPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        st = wx.StaticText(groupPanel, -1, "Which characteristics would you like to group by?")

        cbAge = wx.CheckBox(groupPanel, -1, "Age")
        cbMarket = wx.CheckBox(groupPanel,-1, "Market")

        groupSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        groupSizer.AddMany([st,cbAge, cbMarket])
        groupPanel.SetSizer(groupSizer)

        summaryPanel = wx.Panel(self)

        st2 = wx.StaticText(summaryPanel, -1, "What would you like to summarize?")
        cbPremiums = wx.CheckBox(summaryPanel,-1, "Premiums")
        cbClaims = wx.CheckBox(summaryPanel,-1, "Claims")

        summarySizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        summarySizer.AddMany([st2,cbPremiums,cbClaims])
        summaryPanel.SetSizer(summarySizer)

        frameSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        frameSizer.Add(groupPanel,1,wx.EXPAND)
        frameSizer.Add(summaryPanel,1,wx.EXPAND)

        self.SetSizer(frameSizer)

class SASApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.App.__init__(self)
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = SASFrame(parent=None,id=-1,title="HCRFM Custom Report Generator")
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

def main():
    app = SASApp()
    app.MainLoop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I resize the window so that it is really small, it looks like this:

[image: overlap]

How can I prevent this overlapping?  Also, how can I make it so the the user cannot make the window small enough to cut off the text going horizontally? I am not sure if I should worry about the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit your line to this:

```
self.SetSizerAndFit(frameSizer)
```

It is going to behave exactly as you would expect. It will layout your widgets to minimum size window (add borders or spaces if / where you need it) and it will never allow smaller window than that. More information in wx docs: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetSizerAndFit

Answer (score 1):

The way I do is to determine and fix the minimum size of the window that prevents unwanted hiding of widgets. I use [wx.Window method](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetMinSize):

```
SetMinSize((x,y))
```

wx.Window has another [alternative method](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#SetSizeHintsSz):

```
SetSizeHintsSz(self, minSize, maxSize=DefaultSize, incSize=DefaultSize)
```

> Allows specification of minimum and maximum window sizes, and window
>   size increments. If a pair of values is not set (or set to -1), the
>   default values will be used. If this function is called, the user will
>   not be able to size the window outside the given bounds (if it is a
>   top-level window.) Sizers will also inspect the minimum window size
>   and will use that value if set when calculating layout.
>
> The resizing increments are only significant under Motif or Xt.